# No result in TableView

Tags: java, json, javafx, jackson, fxml

I have problem with show one column in **TableView**. I get data with JSON.
Query:

```
[{"idmarks":3,"idusers":1,"mark":8.0,"test":{"date":"2016-01-01T12:34:59+01:00","idtests":2,"title":"test 2"}},{"idmarks":4,"idusers":1,"mark":4.0,"test":{"date":"2014-01-01T11:11:11+01:00","idtests":3,"title":"test 111"}}]
```

Code:

```
@FXML
private void action(){
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    List<Marks> lista = null;
    String path = "http://localhost:8080/Server/source/users/1/marks";
    try {
        lista = mapper.readValue(new URL(path), new TypeReference<List<Marks>>(){});
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }

    ObservableList<Marks> lis = FXCollections.observableArrayList(lista);
    table.setItems(lis);

    TableColumn<Marks, String> first = new TableColumn<Marks,String>("Mark");
    first.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("mark"));
    TableColumn<Marks,String> second = new TableColumn<Marks,String>("Title");
    second.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("title"));

    table.getColumns().setAll(first, second);  
}
```

[Marks.java](http://pastebin.com/AadPQ4KS)

and score:

[image: TableView]

Comment: Can you show the `Marks` class? Also please check, if the values are read from JSON correctly...

Comment: Yes, of course. Please [Marks.java](http://pastebin.com/AadPQ4KS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convenience implementation `PropertyValueFactory` cannot retrieve a "property of a property": i.e. it cannot get the `title` property from the `test` property of your `Marks` instance. Implement the `Callback` yourself:

```
second.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> 
    new SimpleStringProperty(cellData.getValue().getTest().getTitle()));
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank @James_D